# Map Java to Mongo Object with a custom structure

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm usig a Mongo Database and Java with Spring backend. I originally has this data structure:

```
"defaultActivation":{
    "accounts": ["500026", "500027"]
}
```

And I was mapping it with this Java code with the getters and setters:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> defaultActivation;
```

But now my structure more complex:

```
"defaultActivation":{
    "accounts": ["500026", "500027"],
    "paymentsModel": {
        "TSP": ["CO", "AR"],
        "PSP": ["CO"]
    }
}"
```

How can I map this model structure, should I have to create a Java model?

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of preference. However, the more complex your data structures are and the more frequently they are used, the earlier you should consider using Java objects rather than stuffing your JSON model into `java.util.Map`s. It might be a little overhead to create a class for your Account and PaymentModel, but it will be much more readable.

Furthermore you should consider if a `PaymentModel` is something that is more complex that just a string. In that case, you might want to add behaviour and functionality at a later point in time which requires `PaymentModel` to be an object, anyway.